# Random result of write to channel (Go)

Tags: go, concurrency, scheduler, channel

I have the following code:

```golang
func writeToClosedBufferedChannel() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 10
    ch <- 20

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("test")
        ch <- 30
    }()

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("before")
    close(ch)

    fmt.Println("after")
    for value := range ch {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

I have different results of this code:

```
test
before
after
panic: send on closed channel

test
before
after
10
20

test
before
after
10
20
panic: send on closed channel
```

I know, that I can't write to channel after closing, but why it works randomly? I want to check, what will be after writing to closing channel from **sendq**, but now I can't understand it...

Comment: There is no synchronisation between `main`, which eventually closes the channel, and the child goroutine, which sends to that channel. Therefore, there's no guarantee that the goroutine will send to the channel before the latter gets closed. Naively, you could believe that 100ms would be enough for that goroutine to send the value to the channel, but that's just not how concurrency works in Go. Not also that the call to `fmt.Println` and the channel send are not done atomically.

Answer (score 1):

The channel is of capacity 2, so the 10 and 20 will be written to the channel. The goroutine will print "test", and then block because the channel is full. In order for it to write 30, another goroutine must read from the channel first. So after test, "before" and "after" are also printed, and at this point, you have a closed channel, and the goroutine is still waiting to write to the channel. Then you start reading from the channel, and multiple things can happen:

In the first output you showed, the first read from the channel unblocks the goroutine, the goroutine is scheduled by the runtime and sends to a closed channel, causing panic.

In the second output, the goroutine is unblocked, but not immediately scheduled, so the main goroutine reads the two values from the channel and program terminates.

In the third output, the goroutine is unblocked, but scheduled only after the two values are printed but before the program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

When you close a channel, it is no longer valid to send values to it. However, the goroutine you created is still running and tries to send the value `30` to the channel. If the goroutine manages to execute before the main goroutine closes the channel, it will panic with "send on closed channel".

To avoid this panic, you should ensure that the goroutine does not try to send values to the channel after it has been closed. You can use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to wait for the goroutine to finish before closing the channel:

```golang
func writeToClosedBufferedChannel() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 10
    ch <- 20

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("test")
        ch <- 30
        wg.Done()
    }()

    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("before")
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)

    fmt.Println("after")
    for value := range ch {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

This ensures that the goroutine has finished sending values to the channel before it is closed.